# How to solve mouseenter and mouseleave overlapping dilemma?

Tags: javascript, jquery

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/31cn9hno/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hoverExpand').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).find('.productsThumbWrap').stop(true, true).animate({
            "margin-top": "+=108px"
        }, "normal");
        $(this).find('.productsThumbWrap img').stop(true, true).css({
            opacity: 1,
            'transition': 'opacity 0.3s ease 0.35s'
        });
    });
    $('.box').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find('.productsThumbWrap').stop(true, true).css({
            'margin-top': '92px'
        });
        $(this).find('.productsThumbWrap img').stop(true, true).css({
            opacity: 0,
            'transition': 'none'
        });
    });
});
```

this does exactly what I want but there is one problem. Try to mouseenter into button from `.hoverExpand` and move up to `.hoverExpand`, the mouseenter re-trigger. How to prevent that?

Comment: Add a class when you hover, check the class before doing anything

Comment: Do you know you can achieve this using pure CSS? JQuery seems overkill in your case, since you seem to have fixed heights. — Well, it is easier with a CSS preprocessing tool.

Comment: @MartinErnst yes what have u did?

Comment: I only changed `margin-top: +="108px"` to `marginTop: "200px"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a class to indicate that the current item is being hovered. In this case, I added a class of `on` and check the class before executing the mouse enter code. In the mouse leave handler, you just need to remove the `on` class.

http://jsfiddle.net/31cn9hno/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hoverExpand').mouseenter(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass('on')) {
            $this.addClass('on')
            $this.find('.productsThumbWrap').stop(true, true).animate({
                "margin-top": "+=108px"
            }, "normal");
            $this.find('.productsThumbWrap img').stop(true, true).css({
                opacity: 1,
                    'transition': 'opacity 0.3s ease 0.35s'
            });
        }
    });
    $('.box').mouseleave(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find('.hoverExpand').removeClass('on');
        $this.find('.productsThumbWrap').stop(true, true).css({
            'margin-top': '92px'
        });
        $this.find('.productsThumbWrap img').stop(true, true).css({
            opacity: 0,
                'transition': 'none'
        });
    });
});
```